# Emulator will not start (?) with 2.2

Tags: android

I am not sure where to start with debugging this problem so I thought I would make a post. I could not find the same problem anywhere else

- I am using eclipse, windows 7, and installed the android sdk and eclipse plugin both.
- I can create hello-world applications, compile and run them nicely for target 2.1-update1 (7)
- I cannot get the emulator to start for target 2.2 (8). I have tried creating profiles through eclipse, and running them stand alone. What happens is the window comes up and it says "A N D R O I D _" and stays there forever. I left it for hours.
- I tried starting the emulator from the command prompt, identical result.
- I tried the `-wipe-data` command, no change
- I cannot get logcat to work: I start "`emulator -avd phone2.2 -logcat '*'`", then try "`adb -e logcat`" in a different console. the logcat says "- waiting for device -" and never changes. Maybe the emulator never starts?

Can someone please advise me on some things to try?

-- Thanks for your feedback
---- update

i started the emulator with `-show-kernel` and it highlighted some probelms. I will reinstall the SDK as you suggested, but here is the kernal output where the problems arise and where it stops and waits forever:

```
Freeing init memory: 104K
init: cannot open '/initlogo.rle'
yaffs: dev is 32505856 name is "mtdblock0"
yaffs: passed flags ""
yaffs: Attempting MTD mount on 31.0, "mtdblock0"
yaffs tragedy: Bad object type, 43188627 != 11, for object 267386880 at chunk 25
535 during scan
yaffs: dev is 32505857 name is "mtdblock1"
yaffs: passed flags ""
yaffs: Attempting MTD mount on 31.1, "mtdblock1"
yaffs_read_super: isCheckpointed 0
yaffs: dev is 32505858 name is "mtdblock2"
yaffs: passed flags ""
yaffs: Attempting MTD mount on 31.2, "mtdblock2"
yaffs_read_super: isCheckpointed 0
init: cannot find '/system/bin/sh', disabling 'console'
init: cannot find '/system/bin/servicemanager', disabling 'servicemanager'
init: cannot find '/system/bin/vold', disabling 'vold'
init: cannot find '/system/bin/netd', disabling 'netd'
init: cannot find '/system/bin/debuggerd', disabling 'debuggerd'
init: cannot find '/system/bin/rild', disabling 'ril-daemon'
init: cannot find '/system/bin/app_process', disabling 'zygote'
init: cannot find '/system/bin/mediaserver', disabling 'media'
init: cannot find '/system/bin/dbus-daemon', disabling 'dbus'
init: cannot find '/system/bin/installd', disabling 'installd'
init: cannot find '/system/etc/install-recovery.sh', disabling 'flash_recovery'
init: cannot find '/system/bin/keystore', disabling 'keystore'
init: cannot find '/system/etc/init.goldfish.sh', disabling 'goldfish-setup'
init: cannot find '/system/bin/qemud', disabling 'qemud'
init: cannot find '/system/bin/logcat', disabling 'goldfish-logcat'
<waits here>
```

Comment: Turns out i just had to reinstall the 2.2 (8) sdk package through the android SDK manager. What a pain :) Thanks for the suggestion, I should have tried that earlier.

best

Jim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The emulator is offline until the chrome android splash. At that point eclipse attempts to connect to the emulator and upload your apk. You can watch this in the DDMS perspective within Eclipse. In your case I would try to reinstall the correct sdk, the emulator is in the tools dir, followed by the obligatory hard windows restart. Then come back and make sure everything is installed correctly in AVD manager and try to run your project.

I will add that I had an issue with several Eclipse libraries on Win7 64

Comment: I'm gl;ad you got it sorted out. Sometimes it's the easiest solutions. If my answer helped please click the check next to the answer box